# OnEdit timestamp on several rows at one time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have set up a timestamp `onEdit` code that works. I have used a code from a Youtube video and edited to suit my sheet, it's safe to say that I'm not an expert on script writing. However the sheet the code is working on has 1000s of rows of data and we can update 100 of rows at once. I need the time stamp script to update several rows one at a time, not just the first row edited.

The script I have is below.

```
function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables
  var startRow = 2;
  var targetColumn = 33;
  var ws = "Database";
 
  //getmodofied row and column
   
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
 
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){
 
    var currentDate = new Date();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,50).setValue(currentDate);
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49).getValue() == ""){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49).setValue(currentDate);
    } // END IF check if date created exists
  } // END IF check column, row, worksheet
} //
```

Comment: I would try a for loop like for(var i=0;i<e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1;i++) {let row=e.range.rowStart+i;.... and write the rest of your code.  Keep in mind that simple triggers have to complete within 30 seconds or they will time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addTimestamp(e){
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart == 33 && e.range.rowStart > 32 && sh.getName() == "Database"){
    let cd=new Date();
    let vs=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,49,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,2).getValues();
    vs.forEach((r,i)=>{r[1]=cd;if(r[0]==''){r[0]=cd;}});
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,49,vs.length,2).setValues(vs);
  }
}
```

I tested this on my account. It works

Comment: Cooper, Thank you this has worked brilliantly! I have once a slight issue that you might be able to help with. In the "database" tab we transfer data in from another sheet. When this is transferred across a timestamp is not applied. I would think that would need to be a change in the script of the other sheet, but wanted to check.

Comment: Is the transfer done by user edit or a script edit.  onEdit() only responds to user edits.  You should probably submit another question so that we can before to get all of the unique requirements for that modification..

Comment: Thanks, will do. To confirm the transfer is completed by another script, a manually initiated macro script, but a script.

Comment: If it's done by another script then onEdit will not trigger

Answer (score 1):

Things that you should have in mind about the script in the question

- `e` holds an event object
- `e.range` holds the Range object that was edited
- `e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,50)`,  `e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49)` return a single cell Range

Quick and dirty fix

Replace

```
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,50)
```

by

```
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,50,e.range.getRows(),1)
```

The above fix will return a Range having the same number of rows than the edited range but only one column

Replace

```
if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49).getValue() == ""){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49).setValue(currentDate);
}
```

by

```
 var values = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49,e.range.getRows(),1).getValues(); 
 var newValues == values.map(row => {
   return row[0] === '' ? currentDate : row[0];
 }
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49,e.range.getRows(),1)e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,49,e.range.getRows(),1).setValues(newValues);
```

`values` will hold the values of column 49, starting and ending on the same rows than the edited range but having only 1 column. `Array.prototype.map` will iterate over all the values. Instead of using a if statement it is using a conditional (ternary) operator, and instead of `setValue`, it's using `setValues` to pass all the values at once.